# Evaluating PlusMinus to 2 decimal answers

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, built-in-symbols, around

How do I evaluate and expand an expression containing `PlusMinus` such that:

```
N[PlusMinus[1, 1]]
```

returns

> 2, 0

I'm stuck at `PlusMinus[1, 1]` giving me `1 \[PlusMinus] 1` ($1 \pm 1$) which is not very helpful for when I'm trying to evaluate larger equations in decimal form.

Are there scalable alternatives?

---

**Edit**:
I don't have to use `N[ ]`, a different function is perfectly fine (as long as I get a decimal answer).

Comment: `PlusMinus[1, 1] /. PlusMinus[a_, b_] :> {a + b, a - b}`

Comment: @Syed Thank you, that is exactly what I'm after. Feel free to post that as an answer and I will mark it as correct

Comment: With v12.0 or later, use `Around[1, 1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, What's the difference / advantage?

Comment: Read the docs for [`Around`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html). You can do operations with them and the uncertainty is tracked.

Comment: I will request Bob Hanlon to write an answer about using `PlusMinus` and `Around` as I don't know much about `Around` at this point.

Comment: `Around` is what I'd recommend too, if you're managing uncertainty. You can also easily convert an `Around` expression into an `Interval` by just prefixing it (`Interval[Around[1,1]]`), and `Interval`s can be used in nice ways too—see the help docs. To do what you want to do here, you could do `MinMax[Interval[Around[1,1]]]`. (You could also streamline this by defining e.g. `extrema[a_Around] := MinMax[Interval[a]]`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = Around[1, 1]
```

[image]

```
a == Around[NormalDistribution[1, 1]]

(* True *)

b = Around[3, 1]
```

[image]

```
b == Around[NormalDistribution[3, 1]]

(* True *)

a + b
```

[image]

Compare with

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[a2 + b2,
   {a2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1., 1.],
    b2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[3., 1.]}];

#[dist] & /@ {Mean, StandardDeviation}

(* {4., 1.41421} *)
```

**EDIT:** As recommended by @thorimur, if the purpose is not to represent uncertainty, then use [`Interval`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html)

```
a = Interval@Around[1., 1.] // Chop

(* Interval[{0, 2.}] *)

MinMax@a

(* {0, 2.} *)

b = Interval@Around[3., 1.]

(* Interval[{2., 4.}] *)

MinMax@b

(* {2., 4.} *)

c = IntervalUnion[a, b]

(* Interval[{0, 4.}] *)

MinMax@c

(* {0, 4.} *)

d = a + b

(* Interval[{2., 6.}] *)

MinMax@d

(* {2., 6.} *)
```

Or use [`CenteredInterval`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CenteredInterval.html)

```
a = CenteredInterval[1., 1.]
```

[image]

```
Information[a, "Bounds"] // N

(* {-1.86265*10^-9, 2.} *)

b = CenteredInterval[3., 1.]
```

[image]

```
Information[b, "Bounds"] // N

(* {2., 4.} *)

c = IntervalUnion[a, b]
```

[image]

```
Information[c, "Bounds"] // N

(* {-7.45058*10^-9, 4.} *)

d = a + b
```

[image]

```
Information[d, "Bounds"] // N

(* {2., 6.} *)
```

Comment: I'll note that in terms of the original question ("evaluating" plus-or-minus), OP specifically seems to want e.g. `MinMax@Interval@Around[1,1]` so as to give `{0,2}`.